# ASP.NET MVC: ModelState error message not being displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am just a beginner of ASP.NET MVC. I just started with creating my login page it works fine but I have a problem when the user inputs wrong credentials. This is what I have done:

**UserProfile**

```
public partial class UserProfile
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required.")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required.")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
```

**HomeController:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(UserProfile objUser)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (DB_Entities db = new DB_Entities())
            {
                var obj = db.UserProfiles.Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(objUser.UserName) && a.Password.Equals(objUser.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (obj != null)
                {
                    Session["UserID"] = obj.UserId.ToString();
                    Session["UserName"] = obj.UserName.ToString();
                    return RedirectToAction("UserDashBoard");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Credentials");
        }
        return View(objUser);
    }

    public ActionResult UserDashBoard()
    {
        if (Session["UserID"] != null)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
    }
}
```

And the **View**

```
@model MyWebApplication.Models.UserProfile

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

I am not sure why the message "Invalid Credentials" is not being displayed when the user types a username that isn't stored in the database.

Comment: It's not displaying because the flow of your program does not set the model state error if the credentials are invalid.  You set the error only if `ModelState.IsValid` is false.  If it's true, you are authenticating the user but not returning an error if invalid.

Comment: Under no circumstances do you ever store a password in a database as plain text - your hash (and salt) them. And I strongly suggest your work though [Security, Authentication and Authorization](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your question you don't state whether or not in your `if` statement if the line `ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Credentials");` is being hit, which I doubt it is.

Your `if` statement is constructed wrong, because as of now you're only wanting to display the `Invalid Credentials` error if the ModelState is not valid.. not whether or not the user's credentials exist.

So you need to rewrite your if statement to this:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    using (DB_Entities db = new DB_Entities())
    {
        var obj = db.UserProfiles.Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(objUser.UserName) && a.Password.Equals(objUser.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (obj != null)
        {
            Session["UserID"] = obj.UserId.ToString();
            Session["UserName"] = obj.UserName.ToString();
            return RedirectToAction("UserDashBoard");
        }       
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Credentials");
        }
    }
}
```

*Not to be picky, but hopefully your `UserName` property is **unique**, because if you have 2 users that have the same exact `UserName` and `Password` and you get the `FirstOrDefault` occurrence, then you could possibly be letting a user sign in with another's credentials.  So I would ensure that the `UserName` property is unique and change `FirstOrDefault` to `SingleOrDefault`.*

But if it does, then here is what needs to change:

**Option 1**

If you want the error message to be displayed under the textbox then in your controller change this:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Credentials");
```

To:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "Invalid Credentials");
```

`AddModelError` takes 2 parameters.. the `key` and the `errorMessage` for that key.  The `key` is the property name in your model.

```
public void AddModelError(
    string key,
    string errorMessage
)
```

**Option 2**

If you do not want to display the error message under the textbox, but rather at the top of the form:

Then change this:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

To:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

For option 2, you need to read the overloaded methods carefully.  Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationsummary(v=vs.118).aspx) in correlation with how you have your `ValidationSummary` setup.. the first parameter is `bool excludePropertyErrors`.. you had that set to **true** so you were **excluding** Property errors, which is why I proposed to change that to **false**, so Property errors would be **included**.

```
public static MvcHtmlString ValidationSummary(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    bool excludePropertyErrors,
    string message,
    IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes
)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! it worked. A very helpful explanation. Yes the username is unique so I changed it to SingleOrDefault. Thank you again!